# Macro Help: Finding a replacement for Cut and Delete for Speed

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I’m looking for a way around using the commands

.delete

.cut

In my excel macros. I’m finding that these processes greatly slow down the procedure (by up to 20 min) for the more data it has to cut paste and delete. Also these processes seem to deactivate my status bar updates from the macro.

I use these commands to move a row (1st column to 374th column) of data into a different worksheet if it meets a certain criteria.

Here is the macro process I use with these commands:
The main lines of concern I have is with 350, 353 and 357

```
328      j = 0
329      FinalRowMF = Worksheets("Main Frame").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
330      FinalRowAr = Worksheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

331      For k = 7 To FinalRowMF
332          Application.StatusBar = "Ignore = " & Ignore & "                    Current File " & ImportDate - FirstDateImport + 1 & " of " & LastDateImport - FirstDateImport + 1 & " = " & fileName & "                    Loop k = " & k - 6 & " of " & FinalRowMF - 6
333          If Worksheets("Main Frame").Cells(k, 6).Value = "" Then
334              j = j + 1
335          End If
336      Next k
337      Worksheets("Archive").Activate
338      If j = 0 Then
339      Worksheets("Archive").Range(Cells(7, 9 + DaysOffset), Cells(FinalRowAr, 9 + DaysOffset)).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    GoTo NoInactives:
340      End If
341      ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = DaysOffset
342      Worksheets("Archive").ListObjects("Table24").Resize Range("$F$6:NJ" & FinalRowAr + j)
343      With Worksheets("Archive").Range("$I$" & FinalRowAr + 1 & ":NJ" & FinalRowAr + j).Interior
344                                                                                      .Pattern = xlNone
345                                                                                      .TintAndShade = 0
346                                                                                      .PatternTintAndShade = 0
347      End With

348      m = j
349      For n = 7 To FinalRowMF - j
350      Application.StatusBar = "Ignore = " & Ignore & "                    Current File " & ImportDate - FirstDateImport + 1 & " of " & LastDateImport - FirstDateImport + 1 & " = " & fileName & "          Finding and Moving ID " & j - m + 1 & " of " & j & "                    Loop n = " & n - 6 & " of " & FinalRowMF - 6
351          If Worksheets("Main Frame").Cells(n, 6).Value = "" Then
352              FinalRowAr = Worksheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
353              Worksheets("Main Frame").Rows(n).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range(Cells(FinalRowAr + 1 - m, 1), Cells(FinalRowAr + 1 - m, 374))
354              Worksheets("Archive").Range(Cells(FinalRowAr + 1 - m, 1), Cells(FinalRowAr + 1 - m, 374)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
355              Worksheets("Archive").Cells(FinalRowAr + 1 - m, 8).Borders(xlEdgeTop).ThemeColor = 1
356              Worksheets("Archive").Cells(FinalRowAr + 1 - m, 8).Borders(xlEdgeTop).TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
357              Worksheets("Main Frame").Rows(n).Delete Shift:=xlUp
358              If m = 0 Then
359              Else
360              n = n - 1
361              m = m - 1
362              End If
363          End If
        If m = 0 Then GoTo LastReplaced:
364      Next n

LastReplaced:

365      Application.StatusBar = "Ignore = " & Ignore & "                    Current File " & ImportDate - FirstDateImport + 1 & " of " & LastDateImport - FirstDateImport + 1 & " = " & fileName & "                    Loop k Counter Result j = " & j
366      Worksheets("Archive").Range(Cells(7, 9 + DaysOffset + 1), Cells(FinalRowAr, 9 + DaysOffset + 1)).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
367      ArDateChange = ImportDate - 1
368      ArSort = True
    GoTo SetMonth:

ArSort:

369      With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive").ListObjects("Table24").Sort
370              .SortFields.Clear
371              .SortFields.Add(Range("Table24[[#All],[" & DayValue & " - " & MonthName & "]]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.ColorIndex = xlNone
372                  .Header = xlYes
373                  .MatchCase = False
374                  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
375                  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
376                  .Apply
377              .SortFields.Clear
378              .SortFields.Add(Range("Table24[[#All],[" & DayValue & " - " & MonthName & "]]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 65535
379                  .Header = xlYes
380                  .MatchCase = False
381                  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
382                  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
383              .SortFields.Clear
384              .SortFields.Add(Range("Table24[[#All],[" & DayValue & " - " & MonthName & "]]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 49407
385                  .Header = xlYes
386                  .MatchCase = False
387                  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
388                  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
389                  .Apply
390              .SortFields.Clear
391              .SortFields.Add(Range("Table24[[#All],[" & DayValue & " - " & MonthName & "]]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 230
392                  .Header = xlYes
393                  .MatchCase = False
394                  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
395                  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
396                  .Apply
397              .SortFields.Clear
398              .SortFields.Add(Range("Table24[[#All],[" & DayValue & " - " & MonthName & "]]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = 16711935
399                  .Header = xlYes
400                  .MatchCase = False
401                  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
402                  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
403                  .Apply
404              .SortFields.Clear
405      End With

NoInactives:
```

PS If someone also knows how to shorten the sorting that would be great too.

Answer (score 3):

In general the quickest way to transfer data is through assignment:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C10").Formula =  
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10").Formula
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C10").Interior.Color =  
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10").Interior.Color
```

Note that you don't need to assign values, if you're assigning the formula.

I don't see how you're going to get out of `.delete`.

In the end, it may be simpler to just refactor your spreadsheet so that the `.delete` doesn't need to happen.

Comment: Look at Line 353 for the .cut reference. Your suggestion will copy only the values correct? I need to copy formulas, and cell fill colours

Comment: @B-B, ok I see it now (wish searched worked good in the edit box).  You could also directly assign the formulas and cell fill colours, using the same Range objects (just different properties).  I would try that out and see if it speeds things up.  It might be (and I would think) that .cut is the real problem.  Answer edited.